# Implement bottomSheet behavior in fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, bottom-sheet

I am trying to implement bottom sheet behavior to fragment.The two points are need to implents
i)calling one fragment to another when button is clicked.
ii)apply bottomsheet behavior to fragment B,So that When I drag down the fragment can hide/dismiss.
Currently I am having two fragment A,B.I call fragment B in Fragment A by a container When button is clicked .

But when I am trying to implent second point I get error.On FrgmentB I am extend only Fragment not Fragmentdialog. The main reason is I cannot able to acess the background UI.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem before, what I did is change the fragment to BottomSheetDialogFragment and made some changes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I created a costume `BottomeSheetFragement` by extending `DialogFragment()`. I did not use `BottomSheetDialogFragment` like mentioned in the previous comment due to some problems with Jetpack Compose and `BottomSheetDialogFragment()`. But if you are not using Jetpack Compose at all or don't run into any problems, I definitely recommend using `BottomSheetDialogFragment()` before my solution.

```kotlin
open class BottomSheetFragment : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: BottomSheetFragmentBinding

    private var initialTouchY: Float = 0f
    private var currentOffset: Int = 0
    private var prevY: Int = 0
    private var initialHeight: Int = 0

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = BottomSheetFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)

        view.post {
            initialHeight = view.height
        }

        dialog?.window?.decorView?.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
            override fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                when (event.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        initialTouchY = event.rawY
                        return true
                    }

                    MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                        dialog?.window?.attributes?.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM
                        val deltaY = (event.rawY - initialTouchY).toInt()
                        val offsetBy = deltaY - prevY

                        dialog?.window?.attributes?.dimAmount = (1 - (currentOffset.toFloat().div(initialHeight.toFloat()))) * 0.6f

                        dialog?.window?.setLayout(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            initialHeight
                        )

                        view.offsetTopAndBottom(offsetBy)
                        currentOffset += offsetBy
                        prevY = deltaY

                        return true
                    }

                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                        if (currentOffset < initialHeight * 0.4) {
                            val resetValue = -currentOffset

                            view.offsetTopAndBottom(resetValue)
                            dialog?.window?.attributes?.dimAmount = 0.6f
                            dialog?.window?.setLayout(
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                initialHeight
                            )
                            currentOffset = 0
                            prevY = 0
                        } else {
                            dismiss()
                        }
                        v?.performClick()
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return false
            }
        })
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val window: Window? = dialog?.window
        window?.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        window?.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/standard_bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```